# How do I install Python 2.7 modules on Windows 64-Bit?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, module, pip

I've been looking around the internet for days now and cannot find a solution to my problem. I've learned all the basics to programming in Python 2.7 and I want to add Pip to my copy of 2.7. I found the link to download the unoffical 64-Bit installer (www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), but when I downloaded it and ran it, it said I needed to have Python 2.7 (which I do) and it couldn't find it in the registry. I went to Pip's website and downloaded the official Windows installer and unpacked it using WinRAR.

I then tried opening Command Prompt and changed the directory to where the get-pip.py is located and running `get-pip.py install` but it says it failed to install.

I am completely lost and really need detailed and clear help. Please answer!

Comment: Did you install the 32-bit Python rather than the 64-bit Python? If so, download the 32-bit installer for pip from that pip, rather than the 64-bit one.

Comment: I downloaded the 64-Bit one. But that was off the unofficial site. Are you saying I should download the 32-Bit version even if I have a 64-Bit machine? And from where? The unofficial one or the real Pip website?

Comment: Note that in this case there are actually _three_ distinctions between 32-bit and 64-bit to consider. The first is Windows for which you have the 64-bit version. The second is for Python which is located at https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.8/. In general, you may consider only using the 64-bit version if you specifically need it, since some compiled modules may have compatibility issues. The third is for pip itself, and the version you would install would depend on the version of Python you installed _not necessarily_ your version of Windows. HTH.

Comment: Also, note that pip does _not_ install Python; you have to install Python from the link I provided above

Comment: Yes, I have Python on my system.

Comment: @Woops: Your problem is almost certainly that you downloaded and installed 32-bit Python. This means that you need 32-bit versions of any binary packages (including pip). Or you can uninstall Python and start over again with 64-bit Python. Either way works.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `easy_install` if you've installed `pip`? Use `pip`! More importantly, your new question is a completely separate question, and you should post it as a new question. Also, as I said in my answer, just saying things like "it says invalid syntax" doesn't help anyone. Copy and paste the actual output into your question.

Comment: Ok. Do you just type pip beautifulsoup4 install?

Comment: @abarnert, I typed pip install beautifulsoup4 into the Python command line but it still says invalid syntax.

Comment: @Woops: Do not try to edit your question into a completely different question that makes the existing comments and answers irrelevant. That makes it impossible for anyone to help you, and it means anyone with a similar problem who finds your question in a search will get the wrong information. Create a new question.

Comment: Also, `pip install beautifulsoup4` is a command that you run from your DOS prompt, not from within Python. If you haven't read at least the [quickstart tutorial](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/), please do so before asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what kind of *machine* you have. You can run 32-bit Windows on a 64-bit machine. And you can run 32-bit Python on 64-bit Windows.

If you have 32-bit Python, you need to install 32-bit pip. (Or you need to switch to 64-bit Python.)

From your description, you most likely have 32-bit Python on 64-bit Windows, and tried to use a 64-bit pip.

---

PS, if you want to install it manually instead of using Gohlke's installer, nobody can help you debug your problem based on "it says it failed to install". It produces a lot more output than that, and without that output, it's impossible to know which of the billion things that could possibly go wrong actually did.

PPS, just installing pip is sufficient to install any pure-Python packages. But if you want to install packages that include C extensions, you will need to set up a compiler (either MSVC, or MinGW/gcc), as explained in the pip documentation.

Comment: How do I use easy_install to install Beautifulsoup4? I typed import pip into the Python command line and it didn't return any errors so I assume that means it installed. It says invalid syntax when I type easy_install beautifulsoup4

Comment: @Woops: You don't use `easy_install`. That's why you installed `pip`. You `pip install beautifulsoup4`. If that doesn't work, that's a completely different problem from not being able to install `pip`, so instead of trying to follow up here, accept an answer, or write and accept your own answer, or delete your question, and then create a new question.